# Data API with Influx-DB and FastAPI

Tags: python, performance, beginner, api, database

I'm fairly new to time series databases in general and Influx in particular.

My objective is to build a simple and general-use API that will allow me to write and read data from an Influx Database.

I used Influx on a previous project and I found that building the API for the database was pretty mechanical, so I decided to create a general API.

I divided my code into 3 modules:

- Main.py where I will run FastAPI
- Database.py where I connect with the database and I set the writing and reading actions.
- Model.py where I create the pydantic model for the API.

### Main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
import yaml
from yaml.loader import SafeLoader
from Model.Model import WritingData, ReadingData
from Database.Database import InfluxDataBase



with open("config.yaml", "r") as ymlfile:
    cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile,Loader=SafeLoader)
server_URL=cfg["InfluxDB"]["server_URL"]
token=cfg["InfluxDB"]["token"]
org=cfg["InfluxDB"]["org"]

Influx = InfluxDataBase(server_URL,token,org)
app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/write/')
async def call_writing_influx(data: WritingData):
    Influx.write_data(data)

@app.post('/read/')
async def call_reading_influx(data: ReadingData):
    return Influx.read_data(data)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, reload=True)
```

### Database

```
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS
import json

class InfluxDataBase:
    
    def __init__(self,server_URL,token,org) -> None:
        self.client=InfluxDBClient(server_URL, token=token, org=org)
        self.write_api=self.client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)
        self.query_api=self.client.query_api()
        self.server_URL=server_URL
        self.token=token
        self.org=org

    def write_data(self,data) -> None:
        executable_code='Point(data.measurement)'
        n_fields=len(data.field)
        n_tag=len(data.tag)
        for i in range(n_tag):
            executable_code=executable_code+'.tag(list(data.tag.keys())[{}],list(data.tag.values())[{}])'.format(i,i)
        for i in range(n_fields):
            executable_code=executable_code+'.field(list(data.field.keys())[{}],list(data.field.values())[{}])'.format(i,i)
        if data.timestamp is not None:
            executable_code=executable_code+'.time(data.timestamp)'

        Data=eval(executable_code)
        self.write_api.write(bucket=data.bucket_name, record=Data)
    
    
    def read_data(self,data):
        query = f'''
        from(bucket: "{data.bucket_name}")'''+ ''' 
        |> range(start: -{}h, stop: now())'''.format(data.time_interval)+f'''
        |> filter(fn:(r) => r["_measurement"] == "{data.measureament_name}")'''
        for i in range(len(data.tag)):
            if i==0:
                query=query+f'''|> filter(fn:(r) => r["{list(data.tag.keys())[i]}"] == "{list(data.tag.values())[i]}" '''
            elif i<len(data.tag):
                query=query+f''' or r["{list(data.tag.keys())[i]}"] == "{list(data.tag.values())[i]}"'''
        query=query+')'
        if data.field[0]=='All':
            pass
        else:
            for i in range(len(data.field)):
                if i==0:
                    query=query+f'''|> filter(fn:(r) => r["_field"] == "{data.field[i]}" '''
                elif i<len(data.field):
                    query=query+f''' or r["_field"] == "{data.field[i]}"'''
            query=query+')'
        result = self.query_api.query(org=self.org, query=query) 
        results={}
        for table in result:
            for record in table.records:
                results[record.get_field()]=record.get_value()
        return results
```

### Model.py

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List,Dict,Optional
from datetime import datetime

class WritingData(BaseModel):
    bucket_name: str
    measurement: str
    tag: Dict[str,str]
    field: Dict[str,float]
    timestamp: Optional[datetime] = None

class ReadingData(BaseModel):
    bucket_name: str
    time_interval: int
    measureament_name: str
    tag: Dict[str,str]
    field: List[str]
```

My current code works fine, It does what is intended to do.

There is any good practice politics I'm breaking?

Do you have any suggestions to improve it?

Edit: I updated the read_data() function in Database.py because I realized I didn't implemented the Flux code properly.

Comment: By politics do you perhaps mean policies?

Comment: I am having an issue with the Module - Model.Model in the 5th line in Main.Py. It's showing error - Module named Model not Found. Can you please guide me about how can I go about installing it on my IDE. I'm new to APIs as well, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

- `Influx` should not be capitalized as it's a variable name
- None of this code:

```
with open("config.yaml", "r") as ymlfile:
    cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile,Loader=SafeLoader)
server_URL=cfg["InfluxDB"]["server_URL"]
token=cfg["InfluxDB"]["token"]
org=cfg["InfluxDB"]["org"]

Influx = InfluxDataBase(server_URL,token,org)
```

should be done at the global level; but I don't know FastAPI and its Starlette backend well enough to suggest a sane global context alternative. This will take some research on your part.

- Lines like `def __init__(self,server_URL,token,org) -> None:` have a return typehint but no hints on the parameters; you should add these.
- Run a linter. Among other things it will tell you to add spaces around the `=` on statements like `self.org=org`

Moving on:

### The root of all eval

Take a deep breath. Step away from the keyboard for a moment. This code:

```
    executable_code='Point(data.measurement)'
    n_fields=len(data.field)
    n_tag=len(data.tag)
    for i in range(n_tag):
        executable_code=executable_code+'.tag(list(data.tag.keys())[{}],list(data.tag.values())[{}])'.format(i,i)
    for i in range(n_fields):
        executable_code=executable_code+'.field(list(data.field.keys())[{}],list(data.field.values())[{}])'.format(i,i)
    if data.timestamp is not None:
        executable_code=executable_code+'.time(data.timestamp)'

    Data=eval(executable_code)
```

is a true nightmare. It's wholly possible to construct your fluent-interface expression dynamically, using loops, something like (untested)

```
expr = Point(data.measurement)
n_fields = len(data.field)
n_tags = len(data.tag)

for i in range(n_tags):
    expr = expr.tag(
        tuple(data.tag.keys())[i],
        tuple(data.tag.values())[i],
    )
```

and so on. But the way you're casting a dictionary to an indexed sequence there and elsewhere in your code is <s>patently insane</s> non-advisable; just call `items`:

```
expr = Point(data.measurement)

for key, value in data.tag.items():
    expr = expr.tag(key, value)

for key, value in data.field.items():
    expr = expr.field(key, value)

if data.timestamp is not None:
    expr = expr.time(data.timestamp)

self.write_api.write(bucket=data.bucket_name, record=expr)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!! Just what I was looking for, I knew my code was ugly and there must be a cleaner way of doing it. Thank you for the insights!!!! By the way, you mentioned that a piece of my code shouldn't be done at a global level, can you explain me why?

Comment: Global code like this makes it more difficult to unit test, for one thing. Also, what if you wanted two separate in-process FastAPI instances, each with a different database?